TypeError: expect is not a function
Запускаю автотест и почему то вылетает ошибка
import got from "got";
import expect from "expect";

describe("Petstore API testing", () => {
  it("should add new pet to service", async () => {
    let pet_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    const response = await got.post("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet", {
      json: {
        id: pet_id,
        category: {
          id: 2,
          name: "name",
        },
        name: "doogle",
        status: "available",
      },
    });
    const body = JSON.parse(response.body);
    console.log(body)
    expect(body.id).toEqual(pet_id);
  });


TypeError: expect is not a function


Какой фреймворк используете для тестирования?

@SwaD
"mocha": "^10.8.2"

Похоже, что не правильно импортите функцию. В инете вроде как говорят, что import {expect} from 'chai' или import {expect} from 'expect'. В любом случае, почитаейте внимательно доку, по которой делаете, как там эта функция импортируется

спасибо, помогло
